# How to create unique entry in database for new userId?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have customer table where I wanted to store a customer with a cusomerNumber Like

customers table:

```
name   cusomerNumber
john   3456
doe    3457
russel 3458
mathew 3459
```

Now if John comes again instead of giving new cusomerNumber i will assign the old one means 3456
and for the new one should be 3460
But if i go increment process like for new entry cusomerNumber + 1

for new customer after john would be assign as 3457 but which has already in database. How do i make it possible to set 3460 instead of 3457 ..

I have followed the following process which usually increment with 1 with the existing one.

```
    $customerId = DB::table('customers')            
                    ->select('customers.*')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    $customer = new Customer();
    $customer->cusomerNumber = $request->Input(['cusomerNumber']) ?: $customerId->cusomerNumber+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your uniqueID field is set as auto-increment, you don't have to worry about it. Let the table create the IDs on it's own, don't do it with code. What I've described is the standard practice.

Also, it's generally accepted that the uniqueID field is the first field and you should just call it 'id'

Comment: i just give the entity name as uniqueId it's totally difference from the id

Comment: What is the purpose of it? How is that different from the id field?

Comment: i just given a extra entity with a customers table to find out repeated customer..means same customer can come again..and for them i don't to give the new cusomerNumber

Comment: In that case, you just look them up by id. What you're asking for doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by select (column)+1 from table 
and then insert it to your table